# Solution for the consumer / producer task

Tags: c, operating-system, producer-consumer

I have been assigned a piece of coursework to implement a solution for the consumer/producer problem that uses a single producer, a single consumer, and a circular buffer. This should be written in C.

Unfortunately, we have been provided with no learning material and are somehow meant to implement this with no help from the lecturer.

the requirement is as follows:

Requirement: You are asked to implement a solution for the consumer/producer problem that uses asingle producer, a single consumer, and a circular bounded buffer (i.e. of a fixed size containing, e.g.,integer values). Both the producer and consumer generate/consume an unlimited number of items(e.g. integers). I.e., they can be executed in an infinite loop, assuming that the code runs indefinitely.You are free to choose how to implement this approach, however, it may be recommended to usesemaphores. A successful implementation has:

- A circular buffer of which the size is fixed and configurable (e.g. using a define statement)
- Counters that keeps track of the number of items that have been produced/consumed so far(you ignore wrap-arounds of ints/longs)
- An identification number for every item produced, e.g. its index in the sequence of produceditems
- A simple visualisation that demonstrates how the number of items in the buffer evolves overtime. This can be as simple as printing a number of stars every time an item isproduced/consumed, with each star representing one element currently in the buffer
- Correct synchronisation of any critical sections that may be present, and only where it is strictly necessary to do so

If anyone can help me out with how to approach this requirement it would be extremely grateful

Comment: This is likely to be closed for being too vague or too broad. Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions for suggestions on how to ask for help with homework, in a way that builds a generally useful question an answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't provide you with complete solution (neither should I), it is possible to lead you into a good path towards the solution.

The Consumer / Producer problem is a classic problem that involves synchronization, avoiding "hunger" or deadlocks. It is an important problem in Computer Science, given that the solution is really fundamental to, for instance, Operating Systems.

It is a great thing to a CS Student learn, but it may require some time and attention. There is a lot of great sources to study this problem. Here's some.

Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

CS MTU https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/SEMA/TM-example-buffer.html

Also, there is a great load of videos about it:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=producer+consumer+problem

**Remember:** these sources are of great use when you try to understand it, but copying code without comprehending what is happening is a very bad habit that will do nothing but waste your time as a student.

Lastly, as bad as your teacher may be, don't be afraid to contact him and ask for help. Showing interest can really motivate an apparently unmotivated teacher.

So go out there, do a thorough research and dedicate a good time to study this problem and when you start to code and problems starts to appear don't be afraid to ask again about this issue. With your better grasp at the question and a piece of code, it is much easier to help you out.

Hope this helps, though. =)